# what is the most efficient way to create a categorical variable based on another continuous variable in python pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a continuous variable A (say, earnings) in my dataframe. I want to make a categorical variable B off that. Specifically, I'd like to define the second variable as going up in increments of 500 until a certain limit. For instance,

```
B= 1 if A<500
   2 if A>=500 & A<1000
   3 if A>=1000 & A<1500
   ....
   11 if A>5000
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in Pandas? In STATA in which I mostly program, I would either use replace and if (tedious) or loop if I have many categories. I want to break out of STATA thinking when using Pandas but sometimes my imagination is limited.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See the docs for `pandas.cut()`.  Btw, you could do the same thing in stata with `egen` and `cut`.

Comment: Although ```pandas.cut()``` is the better and more general answer, it looks like in this case you could do ```df['B'] = (df.A / 500).astype(int) + 1```. The plus one starts the categorical var at 1. This wont work if A has negative values.

Comment: @JoeCondron  Also note that `cut()` will generate a dtype of categorical rather than integer.

Comment: Cool. I didn't even know this data type existed and I will most definitely be putting it to use in my current project.

Answer (score 1):

If the intervals are regular and the values are positive as they seem to be in the example, you can get the integer part of the values divided by the length of the interval. Something like

```
df['category'] = (df.A / step_size).astype(int)
```

Note that if there are negative values you can run into problems, e.g. anything between -500 and 500 comes out as 0. But you can get around this by adding some base value before dividing. You can effectively define you're catgeories as the multiples of step size from some base value, which happens to be zero above. 
Something like

```
df['category'] = ((df.A + base) / step_size).astype(int)
```

Here'a another approach for intervals which aren't regularly spaced:

```
lims = np.arange(500, 5500, 500)
df['category'] = 0
for lim in lims: 
    df.category += df.A > lim
```

This method is good when you have a relatively small number of limits but slows down for many, obviously. 
Here's some benchmarking for the various methods:

```
a = np.random.rand(100000) * 6000
%timeit pd.cut(a, 11)
%timeit (a / 500).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.47 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 ms per loop

%%timeit
x = 0
for lim in lims: 
    x += a > lim
100 loops, best of 3: 3.84 ms per loop
```

I put `pd.cut` in there as well as per `John E's` suggestion. This yields categorical variables rather than integers as he pointed out which have different uses. There are pros and cons to both approaches and the best method would depend on the scenario.

Comment: pd.cut worked in this case but it's good to learn other approaches. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that `cut` is useful here.  Note that it's somewhat new so make sure you are on a recent version of pandas.